# Problema con firmado de xml con php

Tags: php, xml, cifrado, rsa

buenas tardes compañeros, tengo problemas al generar una firma en un xml, para empezar estos son los "pasos" que me dejan para realizarlo:

1.Aplicar el algoritmo de canonicalización al documento XML, es decir realizar un procesamiento que permita obtener su forma canónica o se normalice el documento original.

2.Aplicara al resultado el algoritmo sha256 a objeto de obtener el HASH.

3.Obtener una cadena aplicando al anterior HASH el algoritmo Base64.

4.Adicionar las etiquetas de signature al XML.

5.Agregar a la etiqueta Digest Value el valor obtenido en el paso 4

6.Tomar la sección de la firma y obtener un HASH del mismo aplicando el algoritmo SHA256.

7..Encriptar el HASH obtenido utilizando el algoritmo RSA SHA256 con la llave privada.

8..Aplicar a la cadena resultante el algoritmo Base64 para obtener una cadena.

9.Adicionar a la etiqueta de Signature Value la cadena anterior.
10.Finalmente colocar en la etiqueta X509 Certificate la llave publica.

11.Devolver el XML firmado.

Bueno, no trabaje con XML, es la primera vez, entonces para facilitarme las cosas, cargo todo en un string, seteo los valores que requiero en el xml antes de seguir los pasos anteriores, finalmente realizo los "pasos" asi por decirlo, agrego los valores de los pasos a la cadena del xml final, vuelco el contenido de la cadena a un fichero xml, lo comprimo y mando al servicio soap, pero el servicio me responde lo siguiente:

```
"protocol" => "HTTP/1.1"
  "status" => "200"
  "codigo_r" => "RECHAZADA"
  "codigoEstado" => 902
  "codigo" => 921
  "descripcion" => "EL FIRMADO DEL XML ES INCORRECTO: Validacion Signature,  false,"
  "transaccion" => false
```

en fin, estos son los pasos que voy realizando, disculpen por la forma, pero aun sigo probando si funciona o no xd:

```
 $firststep_canonic=Utilities::canonicalizeXML($bodyXMLFile); //canonizado del cuerpo xml
        $secodstep_hash=Utilities::eSHA256($firststep_canonic); //obteniendo hash del xml canonizado
        $thirdstep_base64=Utilities::eBase64($secodstep_hash); //nuevo hash en base64
        $fourtFifthhstep_digest=$thirdstep_base64;//"<DigestValue>$thirdstep_base64</DigestValue>";
        $sixthstep_sha256=Utilities::eSHA256($signatureFile);
        
        $public_certf=Storage::disk('public')->get('newcertif/signature.pem'); //firma digital del proveedor soap
        $rsaEncoder=new rsaController();
        $seventhstep_rsa256=$rsaEncoder->createSign($sixthstep_sha256);//7mo paso de cifrado rsa sha256

        $eighthstep_Base64=$seventhstep_rsa256;
        $ninethstep_SignatureVal=eBase64($eighthstep_Base64);//"<SignatureValue>$eighthstep_Base64</SignatureValue>";
        $tenthstep_x509=$public_certf;//"<X509Certificate>$public_certf</X509Certificate>";
        $tenthstep_x509=str_replace("-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n","",$tenthstep_x509);
        $tenthstep_x509=str_replace("\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----","",$tenthstep_x509);

$finalXMLString=
        "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>
            <facturaElectronicaCompraVenta xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"
                                        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation=\"facturaElectronicaCompraVenta.xsd\">
                <cabecera>
                    <nitEmisor>$nitE</nitEmisor>
                    <razonSocialEmisor>$reasonSocialContrib</razonSocialEmisor>
                    <municipio> $city </municipio>
                    <telefono>$phoneDeal</telefono>
                    <numeroFactura>$numberOfInvo</numeroFactura>
                    <cuf>$cuf</cuf>
                    <cufd>$cufd</cufd>
                    <codigoSucursal>$codSuc</codigoSucursal>
                    <direccion>$address</direccion>
                    $nPuntoVenta
                    <fechaEmision>$dateEmit</fechaEmision>
                    <nombreRazonSocial>$reasonSocial</nombreRazonSocial>
                    <codigoTipoDocumentoIdentidad>$typePersonalDocument</codigoTipoDocumentoIdentidad>
                    <numeroDocumento>$nPersonalDocument</numeroDocumento>
                    <complemento xsi:nil=\"true\"/>
                    <codigoCliente>$codClient</codigoCliente>
                    <codigoMetodoPago>$codModPay</codigoMetodoPago>
                    <numeroTarjeta xsi:nil=\"true\"/>
                    <montoTotal>$totalPay</montoTotal>
                    <montoTotalSujetoIva>$subjectIva</montoTotalSujetoIva>
                    <codigoMoneda>$codCurrent</codigoMoneda>
                    <tipoCambio>$typeChange</tipoCambio>
                    <montoTotalMoneda>$totalPayCurrent</montoTotalMoneda>
                    <montoGiftCard xsi:nil=\"true\"/>
                    <descuentoAdicional>$extraDesc</descuentoAdicional>
                    <codigoExcepcion xsi:nil=\"true\"/>
                    <cafc xsi:nil=\"true\"/>
                    <leyenda>$textLaw
                    </leyenda>
                    <usuario>$user</usuario>
                    <codigoDocumentoSector>$typeDocSec</codigoDocumentoSector>
                </cabecera>
                <detalle>
                    <actividadEconomica>451010</actividadEconomica>
                    <codigoProductoSin>49111</codigoProductoSin>
                    <codigoProducto>JN-131231</codigoProducto>
                    <descripcion>JUGO DE NARANJA EN VASO</descripcion>
                    <cantidad>1</cantidad>
                    <unidadMedida>1</unidadMedida>
                    <precioUnitario>100</precioUnitario>
                    <montoDescuento>0</montoDescuento>
                    <subTotal>100</subTotal>
                    <numeroSerie>124548</numeroSerie>
                    <numeroImei>545454</numeroImei>
                </detalle>
<Signature xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#\">
<SignedInfo>
<CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm=\"http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315\"></CanonicalizationMethod>
<SignatureMethod Algorithm=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256\"></SignatureMethod>
<Reference URI=\"\">
<Transforms>
<Transform Algorithm=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature\"></Transform>
<Transform Algorithm=\"http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315#WithComments\"></Transform>
</Transforms>
<DigestMethod Algorithm=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256\"></DigestMethod>
<DigestValue>$fourtFifthhstep_digest</DigestValue>
</Reference>
</SignedInfo>
<SignatureValue>
$ninethstep_SignatureVal
</SignatureValue>
<KeyInfo>
<X509Data>
<X509Certificate>$tenthstep_x509</X509Certificate>
</X509Data>
</KeyInfo>
</Signature>
</facturaElectronicaCompraVenta>";
```

al final solo vuelco esa variable finalxmlstring a un fichero .xml, comprimo y envio al servicio, pero me da el error que comentaba anteriormente.
el fichero signature.pem, me lo da el proveedor de servicio soap, apartir de un fichero que lo genero con openssl desde cli, es una llave publica la que se le manda para que nos devuelva la firma.

La documentacion no esta muy bien detallada, aqui hay las sugerencias del porque no se recibe el xml compreso en el servicio:
Este error de validación es el más común al momento de implementar el método de firmado de una factura XML y se presenta por las siguientes razones:

1.No usar Sha256 versión 1 sino sha2.

2.El certificado con el que realiza la firma debe ser el otorgado por nosotros para pruebas.

3.Verifique que la etiqueta X509Certificate este en el lugar correcto después de firmar la factura XML.

4.Verifique que el XSD con el que está cruzando para validar la firma sea el electrónico no el computarizado.

5.Al momento de generar el XML firmado, verifique que no sufra modificaciones después de la firma.

Ok, entonces para el primer punto, no comprendo muy bien lo del cifrado, la funcion que utilizo para ese "cifrado" es la siguiente y no se si es la forma correcta:

```
public static function eSHA256($value){
        return (hash("sha1",$value));  //vi tambien que hay sha256, no se cual es el adecuado en realidad, diferencias si lei
    }
```

para el punto 2. el certificado si nos lo dieron, es signature.pem generado a partir de un archivo csr que actua como llave publica (creo).

para el punto 3. esta en el lugar correcto dentro del string de finalxmlstring.

en le punto 4, no vi como hacer el cruce del xml con el xsd, encontre un metodo pero no me funciona, me daba error al cargar el XSD   https://www.jc-mouse.net/php/validacion-xml-con-esquema-xsd-en-php

Para la parte del cifrado RSA no encontre mucha información, adecue una sugerencia e hice esta funcion:

```
public function createSign($data = '')
    {
        print_r($this->getPublicKey());
        
        if (!is_string($data)) {
            return null;
        }
        return openssl_sign(
                    $data,
                    $sign,
                    $this->getPrivateKey(),
                    OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256
                  ) ? base64_encode($sign) : null;
    }
```

Tengo dudas en el cifrado sha, y luego en el rsa, creo que ahi es mi falla. ya voy con esto por 3 dias. D:

este me lo encontre por foros como una opcion para el rsa sha

```
public static function encrypt_RSA_Base64($plainData, $privatePEMKey)
    {
        $ENCRYPT_BLOCK_SIZE = 256; //no se si este valor es el correcto
        $encrypted = '';
        $plainData = str_split($plainData,$ENCRYPT_BLOCK_SIZE);
        foreach($plainData as $chunk)
        {
        $partialEncrypted = '';
        $encryptionOk = openssl_private_encrypt($chunk, $partialEncrypted, $privatePEMKey, OPENSSL_PKCS1_PADDING);

        if($encryptionOk === false){return false;}//also you can return and error. If too big this will be false
        $encrypted .= $partialEncrypted;
        }

        //return $encrypted;
        return base64_encode($encrypted);//encoding the whole binary String as MIME base 64
    }
```

y tampoco pasa el envio del xml al servicio si lo utilizo.

Comment: que tal?
Tengo el mismo problema, pudiste solucionarlo?
Si es así, podrias explicarme como lo hiciste pls.